# TinyMCE - Chrome browser - Can't paste images in Chrome as in FF

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome, firefox, tinymce

I'm using the **TinyMCE WYSIWYG editor** control and while it is possible to copy and paste image fractions in ***FireFox***, it is impossible in ***Chrome***.

I've tried upgrading to **TinyMCE** ver. 4.0.16 (previously had ver. 3.5.8) with still no possible way to make it work.

Has anyone been able to do this?

Example to how this looks in FireFox:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You sure there's no console errors (`F12`) when trying to paste? Last reported error seemed to be in [4.0.9](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=32868) (Which you are obviously higher)

Comment: I can reproduce. Using latest Chrome Canary. Hope you find a solution

Comment: No console errors, just plain doesn't work.

Comment: This is not an error of TinyMCE, CKEditor doesn't work too, I think that this is a block of Chrome and IE, but I can't found a solution for this yet :(

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution for this issue, and it has been tested using Chrome v 47.
Here is what you have to do:

```
function pasteHandler(e) {
   var cbData;
   if (e.clipboardData) {
      cbData = e.clipboardData;
   } else if (window.clipboardData) {
      cbData = window.clipboardData;
   }

   if (e.msConvertURL) {
      var fileList = cbData.files;
      if (fileList.length > 0) {
          for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
              var blob = fileList[i];
              console.log("Image blob: " + blob);
              readPastedBlob(blob);
         }
     }
 }
 if (cbData && cbData.items) {
     if ((text = cbData.getData("text/plain"))) {
         // Text pasting is already handled
         return;
     }
     for (var i = 0; i < cbData.items.length; i++) {
         if (cbData.items[i].type.indexOf('image') !== -1) {
             var blob = cbData.items[i].getAsFile();
             readPastedBlob(blob);
         }
     }
 }

function readPastedBlob(blob) {
    if (blob) {
        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(evt) {
            pasteImage(evt.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    }
}

function pasteImage(source) {
    var image = "<img src='" + source + "' data-mce-selected='1'></img>";
    window.tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, image);
}}
```

In the init method of you tinyMCE:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea", // change this value according to your HTML
    paste_data_images: true,
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on('paste', pasteHandler)
    };
})
```

Comment: sorry i tried this code but did not work for chrome 50 and ie11.

Comment: My case, it works fine in IE but not in Chrome, your code fixes it for chrome but it paste twice for IE :)

Comment: This code solved my problem. 
Just remove the   `paste_data_images: true` if you got twice paste problem

Answer (score 4):

I've just got this working.

Remove "Paste" from the plugins list and set "paste_data_images: true"

Works a treat!

Answer (score 0):

I just answered this question. Here's a link to my answer:
[TinyMCE "paste button" does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622887/tinymce-paste-button-does-not-work/37703240#37703240)

at time of the configuration of Tiny MCE, use this to get Chrome to work:

```
tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea', plugins: [
        "image paste"
    ],
    paste_data_images: true});
```