# Disabled cut, copy & paste functions in CKEditor with Firefox and Chrome. Workaround?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, ckeditor

As you can easily test yourself on http://ckeditor.com/demo (v. 4.4.3), the cut, copy and paste functions by means of the buttons and context menu are disabled (i.e. actively blocked) in Firefox(30) and Chrome(35). This has also been the case with earlier versions of the browsers and of (F)CKEditor. With other form text area editors (which CKEditor actually is), the said functions work perfectly well in the two browsers. And with Internet Explorer it has never been a problem, at least up to 9 (cannot test > 9 now).

I've gone through the whole documentation and the CKEditor forums, including the developers/bug report site, but no solution or work-around is offered. Does anyone know one? It would preferably have to be one that is Javascript-based, because I think it is a poor show if we have to ask the users to configure their FF/Chrome to use the editor in a normal way. If that would be possible at all.

Comment: It is a security issue to let browser access clipboard data (no wonder why it works in IE).

Comment: Chrome allows this if you declare permissions to manifest https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions. For Firefox I found this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla#Executing%5FCommands

Comment: @VilleRouhiainen: I've participated in two dozen web dev forums, and in none of the text area editors they used was it ever, or is it, a problem with FF and Chrome. Thanks for the links, which are appreciated. But CKEditor uses an iframe which I cannot change the code of, and configuring Chrome is too much to ask of our clients, IMO. Many of them hardly know anything about configuring browsers.

Comment: If you are using TinyMCE, I have found a solution [http://stackoverflow.com/a/34310270/915591](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34310270/915591)
Maybe you can adapt it for CKE also.

Answer (score 0):

Direct access to clipboard or forcing paste is yet impossible on other browsers than IE. On IE user must accept a security alert to allow this.

If you've ever seen an editor being able to drag content from the clipboard, I suppose it was a Flash or Java solution (entire editor or just the clipboard access). I know of nothing in JavaScript that could help.

Fortunately, situation will change in the future, because a solution is being standardised at the moment. Application will be able to fire paste event from a semi-trusted event. We have to wait a year or two, though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am going to ask the makers of the [**Sitepoint forum**](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?15-JavaScript-amp-jQuery) how they did it, because they are using CKEditor (I believe v. 3). I'll get back on it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using IE11 and have no problem with pasting in-- with Chrome, it pops up a window that claims I can use ctl-V to do it manually, which works with text but given I'm often trying to paste in an image, nothing occurs at all when I try that.   My solution-- recommend users use IE.  My recommendation to browser developers-- if your security solution requires breaking the user's workflow, they will exert far more effort finding a workaround for the problem than they ever would conforming to complicated security procedures.

Comment: I agree with your advice to browser developers, but I would like it very much if my clients could just their normal browser. But then, I guess you would like that, too. There is another issue, however: looking at CKE's own Javascripts, it seems as if the makers of CKE voluntarily chose to go along with the overly strict security rules of the browsers in question. My advice to them would be: give us as CMS developers the choice.