# printscreen + paste image in tinymce and ckeditor editor does not paste the image

Tags: javascript, tinymce, ckeditor

I am using both tinymce editor and ckeditor. In my application, I should be able to printcreen and paste the image in the editors(tinymceditor and ckeditor). However, this works fine in firefox but does not seem to paste the image in the editor in chrome.

With some more research I found the cause to be browser security issues.

I need to make this cross browser problem work.
I am kinda stuck in this part.

How am I to fix this in chrome?

Comment: Try this sample and check if it works exactly as you would expect it to work: http://ckeditor.com/tmp/4.5.0-beta/image-upload.html
If yes, start using CKEditor 4.5 beta.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution to paste screenshots in TinyMCE in Chrome here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34310270/915591