# TinyMCE "paste button" does not work

Tags: tinymce

My question about TinyMCE  editor.
In IE brower it works fine. But when I paste something  in FF & Chrome I'm receiving the message: "Your browser doesn't support direct access to the clipboard. Please use the Ctrl+X/C/V keyboard shortcuts instead."
I've not found any documentation to solve this problem!
I need help ,Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a little late to this, but I was having the same problem. I did some digging, and this configuration worked for me.

```
tinyMCE.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    language: editorLanguage,
    plugins: [
        "autolink lists link image anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks",
        "insertdatetime media contextmenu paste"
    ],
    menu: {
        edit: { title: 'Edit', items: 'undo redo | cut copy paste | selectall' },
        insert: { title: 'Insert', items: 'link image' },
        view: { title: 'View', items: 'visualaid' },
        format: { title: 'Format', items: 'bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript | formats | removeformat' }
    },
    convert_urls: false,
    paste_data_images: true



});
```

At a minimum though, all you need is this:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: "image,paste",
    paste_data_images: true
});
```

This is working for me, using the cdn hosted version ( cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js )

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: but this is not working for me. Used the cdn version used the minimum config too

Comment: Actually the problem is not with settings but rather with JS limitations. Tinymce people say to this: "As the message from the editor states this is simply a limitation of what you can / cannot do directly via JavaScript in certain browsers." See https://community.tiny.cloud/communityQuestion?id=90661000000IgLUAA0 for more information.

Comment: In TinyMCE 6 paste as a plugin is deprecated, as it's now a core part of TinyMCE.
reference - https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/migration-from-5x/